# HTML CSS Design

Tags: .net, html

A hopefully quick, or easy, question:
Would anyone be able to tell me what the ".NET Landscape" is in terms of HTML design?

Thanks!

Comment: You are being very vague. What's your definition of "HTML design"?

Comment: Well yeah, I know I'm rather vague but I've seen a few job ads that state "HTML Design" - I see it as taking Photoshop designs and essentially creating the HTML/CSS from it. The "HTML Design" was on a job spec..  and another requirement is "Understanding of .Net landscape"  - As Batwad mentions..  could well be management talk???  Hmm...

Comment: Do you want to know about ASP.NET? The .NET Framework really doesn't have anything to do with HTML itself, although they are cooperative technologies, each has its own function. Can you be any more specific?

Answer (score 1):

Management speak?

Answer (score 0):

More than likely, they have nothing to do with one another. If you saw them on a job spec, they were probably just listing the technologies they expect you to be familiar with. Something like this:

- HTML
- CSS
- Microsoft .NET Framework

  - including languages like C# and VB.NET
  - technologies like WinForms, WPF, ASP.NET, Silverlight, etc.
  - common design practices and patterns

Of course, certain .NET technologies work together with HTML. For example, ASP.NET provides something called "web forms," which contain static HTML markup as well as server-side Web Controls and User Controls to provide dynamic content. Also, Silverlight applications are hosted on and loaded from an HTML page.

If you're unsure what exactly would be expected of you, I recommend that you find out more details.